# Android settings and Microsoft Intune report different security patch levels on Huawei devices

Tags: updates, huawei, android-versions, operating-system, microsoft-intune

I have a Huawei P20 lite, which reports (per System -> About this phone) an OS version EMUI 9.1.0, Android 9, Kernel 4.9.148, Security Patch Level of 1st January 2022.

However, Microsoft Intune reports an OS version of Android 9.0 and a Security Patch Level of 2020-08-01.

So, which is it? Is the 2022 patch level the patch level of the EMUI part of HUAWEI's Android variant, and the 2020 patch level the latest patch level of the underlying Android version?

Comment: unfortunately it is not really uncommon that devices lie about their (incomplete) patch state: https://www.wired.com/story/android-phones-hide-missed-security-updates-from-you/

Comment: Is this what they mean with "zero trust IT", you can't trust your IT equipment? Jokes aside, this reinforces my view, that smartphones are crappy computers.

Comment: Use the [Snoopstitch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.srlabs.snoopsnitch) app authored by the folks in @Robert link, to find out for yourself

Answer (score 2):

Some suspected that Huawei couldn't get the security patch update on their Android devices certified by Google anymore because of the TGL (Temporary General License) extension timed out in August 2020.

According to comments on the Huawei forum:

- [Android security patch not updated... looks like it.](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/community/details/Android-security-patch-not-updated-looks-like-it/topicId_153126/)

  > I suspect that Huawei cannot get any security patch higher than 08/20 certified on GMS devices because that's the time the TGL (temporary license for existing devices) timed out.
  >
  > At least SnoopSnitch doesn't find any vulnerabilities here on my P30 Pro and does report CVE up to 02/2021 being fixed, so it might be mostly a cosmetic issue.
- [Security Patch Version not recognized by Microsoft Intune](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/community/details/Security-Patch-Version-not-recognized-by-Microsoft-Intune/topicId_158253/)

  > This is a known issue and they (Huawei support) refuse to tell why they keep the outdated patch level of 08/2020 (for GMS devices) or 11/2020 (for HMS devices) in the official Android info field for that parameter.
  >
  > Fact is, in the system info any developer can insert any string they like (so they could tell you even 12/2525 if they wanted to) so what you read there is of no worth at all.
  >
  > Strange enough it seems the security patches after 08/2020 are really applied if you believe testing software but it still reports that stone old patch level leading to severe problems with some software that requires actual patch levels.
  >
  > The only reason for this I can think of is that Huawei isn't able to get those patches officially verified even though the CVEs are included.

And by US governments, [Temporary General License: Extension of Validity](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2020/05/18/2020-10614/temporary-general-license-extension-of-validity)

> The U.S. Government has decided to extend through August 13, 2020, the temporary general license to Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. (Huawei) and one hundred and fourteen of its non-U.S. affiliates on the Entity List. In order to implement this decision, this final rule revises the temporary general license to remove the expiration date of May 15, 2020, and substitutes the date of August 13, 2020. In addition, BIS sought public comments regarding future extensions of the Huawei TGL (85 FR 14428, March 12, 2020) and is in the process of reviewing those comments.